# Print the most frequent (numerical value) name (character string) by race (character string)

Tags: r

Trying to get the #1 most frequent name by race in a cohort of babies born in NYC, 2011. This is what the dataset looks like:

[image: Baby Data]

I want to display the most common `(RNK = "1")` name `(NM)` for black `(ETHCTY = "BLACK NON HISPANIC")` and white `(ETHCTY = "WHITE NON HISPANIC")` subgroups from the female population `(GNDR = "FEMALE")`.

I have tried the `subset` function. Here is the code I tried:

`subset(Baby.names.ethnicity.NYC, select = c(NM, subset=(RNK > 10))),
+              subset=c(ETHCTY == "WHITE NON HISPANIC" & ETHCTY == "BLACK NON HISPANIC" & GNDR == "FEMALE")`

Comment: Looks like you need this logical expression: `data[with(data, ETHCTY %in% c("WHITE NON HISPANIC", "BLACK NON HISPANIC") & RNK == 1 & GNDR == "FEMALE"), ]`

Comment: Also, in your code `ETHCTY == "WHITE NON HISPANIC" & ETHCTY == "BLACK NON HISPANIC"` should be `ETHCTY == "WHITE NON HISPANIC" | ETHCTY == "BLACK NON HISPANIC"` because you want either

Comment: Thank you, @RichardScriven!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    df <- Baby.names.ethnicity.NYC
    top_name <- subset(df, df$GNDR=="FEMALE" & df$RNK == 1 &
    (df$ETHCTY == "BLACK NON HISPANIC" | df$ETHCTY == "WHITE NON HISPANIC"))$NM
```

I took the liberty to shorten the dataframe name, which made the code look less complex.